# Regular expression to extract javascript method calls

Tags: php, javascript, preg-match

I have created string extractor for translations from javascript files.
I found jsgettext project which I used as a starting point ([see](http://code.google.com/p/jsgettext/)).

It uses reqular expression to find calls to `__()` method inside javascript files. The simple calls are found successfully, but calls with arguments like `__('string', { a: 'b'})` are not.

I tried to modify the regular expression to match also method calls with arguments, but without any success (I'm not regular expressions expert).

My question is: **How to modify following regular expression to match strings like this?**

```
// this is catched successfully 
// var string = __("Please enter %number% more characters.");

// this is problematic
var string = __("Please enter %number% more characters.", { '%number%' : 2 });
```

Regular expression:

```
 $keywords = join('|', array('__'));
 preg_match_all('# (?:' . $keywords . ') \(\\ *" ( (?: (?>[^"\\\\]++) | \\\\\\\\ | (?<!\\\\)\\\\(?!\\\\) | \\\\" )* ) (?<!\\\\)"\\ *\) #ix', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Thank you

Comment: This `$keywords = join('|', array('__'));` doesn't make sense to me ...

Comment: This is for a purpose to match other i18n functions. I removed that code from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really need to match whole call like:

```
__("Please enter %number% more characters.", { '%number%' : 2 });
```

You just need to match:

```
__("Please enter %number% more characters.",
```

And leave the rest as it is because those are only arguments that shouldn't be part of translation inside database.

Therefore editing regular expression on lines [81](https://code.google.com/p/jsgettext/source/browse/trunk/JSParser.php#81) and [89](https://code.google.com/p/jsgettext/source/browse/trunk/JSParser.php#89) to finish with `*(?:\)|,) #ix` instead of `*\) #ix` should be good enough.